# is it possible to change the scope of variables with initially equal scopes?

Tags: javascript, scope

i want to know if i can make the scope of a varible go out of a module script tag, or if i can export it in some way and import in another script tag.

my current code is something like this:

```html
<script>
    var variable1 = 'first variable :)';
    var variable2 = 'second variable :)';
</script>
<script>
    // i want to be able to access variable1 here, but not variable2
</script>
```

would something like this be possible?

i already tried `var`, `let`, `const` and `window.`, but they make no difference.
i also tried to make the first script a module, but then i couldn't access `variable1`, and (i think) there's no way to use import/export.

notes:
i only want to separate the scripts into separate files if there is no other option.

Comment: "If you don't want to do something, don't do that thing" applies here. If you're going to use inline scripts (which I would strongly recommend you don't) then all code has the same scope. It doesn't matter whether you've spread it out over multiplt `<script>` tags, that's an HTML thing, not a JS thing. However, what you really want to do instead of start using modern JS and put your code in their own files, as [modern ES modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), so anything that needs something from another scope can literally just import that.

Comment: if you're sure about that, you can answer the question, saying that i have to use separate files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `variable1` and `variable2` are defined in the same scope (at the top level), there's no way to access only one but not the other elsewhere - unless you changed the first script tag to something like

```
<script>
    var variable1 = 'first variable :)';
    (() => {
        var variable2 = 'second variable :)';
        // do stuff with variable2
    })();
    // variable2 cannot be seen outside
</script>
```

> i only want to separate the scripts into separate files if there is no other option

It's a *very good* option that you should consider if you're making something reasonably professional and the code to be written isn't trivial. I highly recommend it, it makes the process of writing and maintaining code much, much easier. Yes, it does take some time to figure out and get used to, but it's worth it, IMO.

Comment: well, the code is actually very trivial, so i think i'm going for the code you showed

Comment: To add to that, we've had [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) for quite a while now, so many servers won't even let you use HTML with inline scripts anymore, since that's the least possible secure way to load scripts (someone could MITM your file, replace the script code, and it'd be considered perfectly fine). Putting your code in their own file both separates your JS from your HTML (which means all your tooling can actually do the right thing) and lets you secure your JS payloads in a way that is compatible with the modern web.

Comment: Sure, if it's trivial, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use a module script and store variables using the window object:

```html
<script type="module">
  var variable1 = 'first variable :)';
  // not accessible by others scripts
  
  window.variable2 = 'second variable :)';
  // accessible by others scripts
</script>

<script>
  console.log(window.variable2)
  setTimeout(() => console.log(variable2), 10)
</script>
```

Comment: i tested it and it does not work, maybe a different js version?

Comment: Just edited the code. It seems to have a delay to work, i didnt know that, i aways used it to debug my codes in the console

Comment: it looks like window.onload = () => console.log(variable2); is enough, problably common scripts are run before modules